# Which $n$ have $\lvert\{2^n-2^k -1\}\cap {\mathrm{PRIMES}}\rvert=m$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, sequences-and-series, oeis

Consider numbers of the form  $2^n - 2^k - 1$ with $k < n$ as considered in OEIS sequence [A208083](https://oeis.org/A208083). As for A208083 I investigated how many of these numbers are prime, but turned the question around: For which numbers $n$ there are $m = 0,1,2,\dotsc$ numbers $k < n$ such that $2^n - 2^k - 1$ is prime. This is the result for $n \leq 28$:

\begin{align*}
n(0) & {}= \{ 1, 2, 7, 15, 23, 27 \} \\
n(1) & {}= \{ 11, 13, 19, 25, 28\} \\
n(2) & {}= \{ 3, 5, 17, 26\} \\
n(3) & {}= \{ 4, 10, 16\} \\
n(4) & {}= \{ 6, 9, 21\} \\
n(5) & {}= \{ 8, 12, 14, 22\} \\
n(7) & {}= \{ 24\} \\
n(9) & {}= \{ 18\} \\
n(12) & {}= \{ 20\}.
\end{align*}

I tried to see a pattern: which $n$ belong to a given $m$? I started by checking if there is an OEIS sequence starting with $n(0) = \{1, 2, 7, 15, 23, 27, \dotsc\}$. But without success. Neither for $n(1) = \{11, 13, 19, 25, 28, \dotsc\}$.

I also entered the sequence of arguments of $n(m)$, i.e. $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,7,9,12,\dotsc\}$. There are [seven OEIS sequences](https://oeis.org/search?q=0%2C1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C7%2C9%2C12) starting with this sequence, but all of them are rather arcane. Only one seems related to prime numbers: [A214120, Number of Proth primes < 2^n](https://oeis.org/A214120).

I wonder nevertheless if there are first-order characterizations of the above sequences. At least: if it can be shown that all $n \in n(m)$ are even when $m>1$ is odd.

More specifically I'd like to know if $n(m) \neq \emptyset$ for all $m$ – and if there can be $m$ with finite $|n(m)|$.

And are Proth primes really related to this problem? (Probably not.)

Comment: I don't see hope for characterizing the preimage of $f$ where $f(n)=|\{ 2^n -2^k-1\}\cap \textrm{PRIMES}|$. What could probably be done is to obtain some probabilistic model for the values of $f$. E.g. Cramér's model suggests $f(n)$ behaves (roughly) like a sum of independent Bernoulli variables $B_1,\ldots,B_{n-1}$ with $\mathbb{P}(B_i=1)=1/\log(2^n-2^i-1)$. There are models such as Granville's model that take into account dependency among small primes and can be used to refine this simplistic prediction.

Comment: I do not see any reason any $m$ cannot be attained. 28 is an extremely small sample; a rough model for how large $n$ you should take to see all values of $m$ up to $M$ attained is given by the coupon collector problem (which you can adapt with some work to your problem in which you morally sample a Poisson distribution and want to obtain certain values).

Comment: The sequence [A208091](https://oeis.org/A208091) gives the smallest member in each $n(m)$. It appears to be unknown whether $n(21)=\emptyset$ or not.

Answer (score 7):

The conjecture is false, eg with $m=5, n=29$ or $m=3, n=49$. Here is some R code, which I ran online at [rdrr](https://rdrr.io/snippets):

```
f = function(n)sum(gmp::isprime(2^n-1-2^(1:(n-1)))/2)
counts = lapply(1:64, f)
lapply(1:64, function(m)which(counts==m))
```